# Any way to know if people are attacking your gym and losing?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just won a gym. Can I detect if people are now attacking my gym and losing? Or, am I just holding the gym because no one is attacking me?

Comment: it's so easy to take a gym it's likely the latter. Unless of course the gym is high level in which case people often give up part way through, either due to a glitch, running out of potions/revives or just because it's taking too long.

Comment: You can see a win count below the Pokémon in a gym. If it's increasing, then yes, they're losing to that Pokémon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect if someone is attacking your gym (or any gym for that matter), but it is not possible to tell if they are winning or losing. In general, if a gym has say 10 Pokemon and then later has 5, you can tell that the gym is losing Pokemon.

When gyms are being attacked, the icon on the top of the gym changes to show tornadoes, storm clouds, lightning, rocks smashing, etc., attacking the gym leader's Pokemon.

In the picture below, you can just barely see the arcs of electricity on the top of this gym controlled by Team Mystic, but it is there. I had a hard time finding images of Pokemon Go gyms being attacked, but there is another image [here](https://i.redd.it/d9vxrnobhv7x.png).

[image]

Comment: Those PokeStops... Well nice answer